# Two way binding for kendo grid template using angular

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

I am rendering a data into kendo grid using angular. One of the column templates in the grid is a select element(using ngSelect and ngOptions). Another column is and anchor link which displays based on the selected option. Now when I select 'Approved' on the select list, i can see the other column changing data. However, when i click the 'Approved' anchor link on the other column, it does not change the select list item. I need to figure out what it is that I am doing wrong to get this working. I am sure I am missing something in the way my scope is working.

Please see demo here: http://jsbin.com/jakerobewa/4/edit

Any inputs suggestions would greatly help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Dumb mistake. dataItem.status is the property I should update. Sorry for wasting everybody's time.